# Problem :Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graphql, cors

I am making graphql services in .NetCore for React application, but I am facing problem with Cors Policy. In console in browser I have the message "has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.".

My Program.cs is

```
var policyName = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";



var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);



builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: policyName,
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder
                            .WithOrigins(React Url)
                            .WithMethods("GET")
                            .AllowAnyHeader();
                      });   
});


builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddGraphQLServer().AddQueryType<Service>().AddMutationType<Mutation>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Windows");
var app1 = builder.Build();
app1.UseHttpsRedirection();
app1.UseRouting();
app1.UseCors(policyName);
app1.UseAuthentication();
app1.UseAuthorization();


app1.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapGraphQL();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app1.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app1.Run()
```

I am running the application with ISS Express.

Comment: What's the value of "React Url"?

Comment: The value is "http://localhost:3000"

Comment: And what does the client code look like?

Comment: (async () =>{
      await fetch(configData.serverURL,{
        method:"POST",
        headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify({query: getCasesQuery})
    })

Comment: Cool, but you should edit your question add the relevant client code there rather than in comment, in which the code is hard to read. You should also specify the Web origin on which your client runs and the actual value of "React Url" there as well.

Answer (score 0):

We can see this statement from [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference#cors-preflight-request):

> A CORS preflight request is used to determine whether the resource
> being requested is set to be shared across origins by the server. The
> CORS preflight uses the HTTP OPTIONS method..... The OPTIONS requests
> are always anonymous, so CORS...

This means the server would not correctly respond to the preflight request if anonymous authentification is not enabled. That's why we need to [install IIS CORS module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cors-in-iis-1) when hosting app in IIS. When we test the API in local machine, we can enable anonymous authentication.

Comment: There's no indication that this is the cause of the OP's problem. The OP _is_ getting a response to the preflight with an ok status, which is encouraging.

Comment: yes, but this is the only related information I found from microsoft. We all know that for CORS issue we need to set allow origins, allow methods ... and OP already did these(except he set a wrong origin url?), and I noticed that he enabled the windows authentication, that's why I think this is the cause. Anyway, we can try to remote the authentication module and test if the cors issue still existed. If it doesn't relate to the authentication, then what I found and what I post are approved not related : (